# Indexes and Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key

My question is about indexes and primary keys.

Let's suppose we have a table like this:

```
demo_table

| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI |         |
| subject              | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |
| body                 | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |
| to                   | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| from                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |
| media                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

I have a query that looks for the last row of a specific 'to' / 'media' couple:

```
select * from demo_table where to="" and media="" order by id desc limit 0,1;
```

and I would like to create an index for my table. Should I create the index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX to_media on demo_table(media,to);
```

or like this:

```
CREATE INDEX to_media on demo_table(id,media,to);
```

seeing that the ID is sorted?

Comment: What is your problem and what is your question?

Comment: Is it MyISAM or InnoDB table? In InnoDB, the PK is always the first  column in index, even if you don't specify it.

Comment: You should be leery of so many columns allowing nulls.  Indexing VARCHAR(255) columns is not necessarily a good idea (though it is not always a bad idea).  Will you ever get the 3-part index used by the query optimizer?  I'm not convinced you would.  You might get the 2-part index used, but I'm not sure whether you'll be using the index enough to warrant its existence.

Comment: the idea is to avoid using the table to order the result, so the index with id key will only be used instead of index + primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE INDEX to_media on demo_table(id,media,to);
```

Comment: it is innodb table.
my problem is to know if there is a difference between two type of indexes I proposed in the question. FYI : In my case there are like >100000 rows to be checked.

Comment: Its depends on the requirement like ...
If its a large scale and more of Insert/update statements go for Innodb other wise go for MYSAM

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on the requirement like ...
If its a large scale and more of Insert/update statements go for Innodb other wise go for MYSAM

please refer the links for further clarification

http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/07/difference-between-innodb-fts-and-myisam-fts/

http://tapos.wordpress.com/2008/01/10/difference-between-innodb-and-myisam/